# Boot a second OS from the same disk (different partition)

Tags: partitioning

I am not sure if I am using the right terminology or not - so please correct me
if I'm stating it wrong ...

What I am trying:

I have a disk with no partitions. And its running some older version of Ubuntu.

I want to create a partition and then install a newer version of Ubuntu and
boot from it.

The device cannot connect to the internet - so standard Ubuntu upgrade cannot
be done. There is a connectivity with another device, via which I can transfer the image.

At a high level, this seems to be possible (?).

I can use `parted` etc. for partitioning. But do I need some special utility to install an OS
image on the second partition (using a `raw` disk image) ?
Do tools like `CloneZilla` help here ?
Any utilities that can make this easier?

Thanks for any hints/pointers.

--

Comment: If the current partitions with the older Ubuntu takes the entire disk, you will need to reduce it using GParted. Take good backups, because an error can destroy this Ubuntu.

Comment: @harrymc yes, that I am already working on. Assuming there is a second vacant partition - are there some known good ways (reliable ones) to boot a new version ?

Comment: Usually just installing it is enough, the GRUB bootloader will take care of everything.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly have at least one partition on your disk :), as you couldn't create any filesystem and install any OS on a disk with **no** partitions at all :)

You don't need any special tools if you want to install a newer version of Ubuntu. Just download a new Ubuntu image, burn it to DVD or create a bootable USB ([here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) is a tutorial on how to create a bootable USB) and boot from that DVD/USB as usual. In the live system you'll find the GParted program that will help you to create a new partition. Then proceed with Ubuntu installation as usual ([here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop) is a tutorial on Ubuntu installation). The Ubuntu installer should detect the previous Ubuntu installation and ask you what to do with it. If there will be an option to install new Ubuntu alongside the previous one, just select it. Otherwise, do it manually. Use custom partitioning and tell Ubuntu to install on the free partition.

If you use custom partitioning, you can even (and I recommend it) create during installation a mount point for your old partition, so you will be able to access the files of your old Ubuntu installation from the new one, under for example `/old` directory (or whatever name you choose).

Ubuntu installer will take care of installing the GRUB menu that allows you to choose during boot, if you want to boot the new or the old system (new will be the default).

If you need more information, you can ask on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com) site.

Comment: I missed adding in the question, I will edit it. There is _no_ internet connectivity to the device and all operations have to be performed remotely. And, none of the standard ubuntu upgrades work without internet!

Comment: How do you want to perform remotely an operation on a device that has no Internet connectivity?
Anyway, OS installation is an operation that requires physical access to the target device. It's not an "upgrade", it's an installlation of a completely new OS. It usually can't be performed remotely, unless you have a customized, fully automated installation media that performs the full installation process after booting without user intervention (this is how servers in the cloud are installed on-demand, they use a highly customized installer).

Comment: As I said in the edit, there is a connectivity to a device, via which I want to transfer an image and install. Customization is one thing - probably you are referring to an ISO kind of customization - but that is not what I am referring to. Assume that there is a disk image prebuilt - sort of like a qcow2 - can this be installed ?

Comment: Do you mean a prebuilt image of an **installed** system? Then you can of course write it to the partition (how, it depends on the format of that image - you can for example use Clonezilla you already mentioned), but after that you'll have to set up GRUB manually to boot from the new partition.

Comment: do you have steps for this ? Have you anytime tried to boot up a disk image by altering grub?

Comment: Yes, I have done this but quite a long ago and don't remember details :). Anyway, I would not risk to do this on a device to which I don't have physical access, in case any thing goes wrong you are left with an unbootable machine. I already suggested that AskUbuntu is a better site to ask these questions than SuperUser. Probably there will be more people there that will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I find it odd that noone has mentioned QEMU, if you want to run the two OS:es at the same time, that is:

```
qemu-system-i386 -cdrom your_new_ubuntu.iso -hda /dev/<insert name of harddrive>
```

for example, I often do when playing around:

```
qemu-system-i386 -cdrom knoppix-std-0.1.iso -hda /dev/sda
```

Comment: But then, the current device becomes a hypervisor - which means performance drastically drops! qemu is not an option here